# add non specific number of dataset rows into a list

Tags: c#, list, foreach, dataset

I am trying to insert a non specific number of rows from a dataset into a list by using a foreach. But I am unsure how to add a non specific number of items to a list from a dataset.

```
public void DeviceReset(string r)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = 
"SELECT installation_id FROM masterinstallationmaps WHERE masterinstallation_id = '" + r + "' ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
```

I am picking out the installation_id from my masterinstallationmap table and if it contains more than 0 rows it should run the foreach to put the rows into the list, otherwise it should run a foreach only inputting 1 item to the list.

```
List<int> instIdList = new List<int>();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        //How to insert all rows from the dataset?
    }
}
else
{
    instIdList.Add(1);
}
```

The else statement works fine, but nothing happens if the Dataset have more than 0 rows.

I am unsure what to put into the foreach:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //How to insert all rows from the dataset?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just add the value like

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    instIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["installation_id"])); 
}
```